# How to convert 16 bit, tiff, Gray-Scale image into 32 bit ,tiff, Gray-Scale Image in java?

Tags: java, image

I m making DesktopApp in java with netbeans platform. In my app i used 16 bit, tiff, Gray-scale Image and processing on that image. Now, i want to make 32 bit, tiff, Gray-Scale image from using 16 bit, tiff, Gray-Scale image (or data of 16 bit image).So how can i convert 16 bit image into 32 bit image in java?

Comment: do you realise you won't get any new data if you do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1177059/converting-a-32bpp-image-to-a-16bpp-image-in-java this is reserve conversion

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov thanks for reply early.Linked given by you is for ARGB image, But im image is Gray-Scale Image not ARGB or RGB. So how can i do Conversion ?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is pass it through an image processor object and then calibrate it. Probably some thing like this :

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import ij.*;
import ij.gui.*;
import ij.measure.*;

/** converting  an ImagePlus object to a different type. */
public class ImageConverter {
    private ImagePlus imp;
    private int type;
    private static boolean doScaling = true;

    /** Construct an ImageConverter based on an ImagePlus object. */
    public ImageConverter(ImagePlus imp) {
        this.imp = imp;
        type = imp.getType();
    }



    /** Convert your ImagePlus to 32-bit grayscale. */
    public void convertToGray32() {
        if (type==ImagePlus.GRAY32)
            return;
        if (!(type==ImagePlus.GRAY8||type==ImagePlus.GRAY16||type==ImagePlus.COLOR_RGB))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported conversion");
        ImageProcessor ip = imp.getProcessor();
        imp.trimProcessor();
        Calibration cal = imp.getCalibration();
        imp.setProcessor(null, ip.convertToFloat());
        imp.setCalibration(cal); //update calibration
    }



    /** Set true to scale to 0-255 when converting short to byte or float
        to byte and to 0-65535 when converting float to short. */
    public static void setDoScaling(boolean scaleConversions) {
        doScaling = scaleConversions;
        IJ.register(ImageConverter.class); 
    }

    /** Returns true if scaling is enabled. */
    public static boolean getDoScaling() {
        return doScaling;
    }
}
```

This way your calibrated image gets set to 32 bit, what ever the input may be . Remember to import the right jars though .

Comment: thanks for reply to me.But i dont want to use ImageJ API. I want to use java's API not Third Party API.

Comment: Alright then , if you are looking for inbuilt API s , then look for the BufferedImage class. What it does is that, it will get the RGB values from one image and store the values in the other image. The BufferedImage class then does the conversion for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your TIFF is loaded as a BufferedImage, you can reduce it this way:

```
BufferedImage convert(BufferedImage image) {

    ColorSpace colorSpace = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);

    ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(
        colorSpace, false, false, Transparency.OPAQUE,
        DataBuffer.TYPE_USHORT);

    BufferedImageOp converter = new ColorConvertOp(colorSpace, null);
    BufferedImage newImage =
        converter.createCompatibleDestImage(image, colorModel);
    converter.filter(image, newImage);

    return newImage;
}
```